# How to serve static files (css, js, img) with NGINX and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nginx, caching

I'm trying to serve css, img and js static files from my public directory (I don't have any html in this directory), so for that I configured my nginx server directive like this:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  my-site.com;
        root         /home/myuser/site/public;

        location / {
               proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000";
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

But nginx server grabs all requests for "/" and tries to give me static files, so I don't see my index.html from node. How to render my index.html on "/" route?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this easily with the following Nginx config.

**Nginx Config**

```
server {
     listen       80;
     listen       [::]:80;
     server_name  my-site.com;
     location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000";
     }

     location /public {
        root /PATH_TO_YOUR_NODE_APP_PUBLIC_DIRECTORY
        expires 30d;
     }
}
```

In your express app .html files access these static files with /public prefix. Example: 'http://sample.com/public/app.css'

Comment: is this a best practice?

Comment: Yes. @Nastro. Because nginx is more powerful in caching than the node server. In fact, you don't need to have the public configuration in the express app. You can move it to the nginx. This reduces the burden for node app. Cheers.

Comment: Do upvote and mark as verified if this solves your problem. So that it will be helpful for others. @Nastro

Comment: What about try_files way. You can serve static files without the need to have a `/public` root path.

Comment: With try_files directive, nginx will try to find the requested resource within the static files and if failed finally it will pass it to the node server. But with my solution we are avoiding unnecessary searching of files by nginx @Clujio

Comment: @Nastro [Nginx webinar for content caching](https://www.nginx.com/resources/webinars/content-caching-nginx-plus/?_ga=2.263580040.524207438.1534337813-2110779395.1531820676) Might me useful for you.

Comment: @Bharathvaj Ganesan thank you very much. Just implement your suggestions and if it work will mark as correct answer.

Comment: @Bharathvaj Ganesan it doesn't work (( node gives me my index but it's without ccs style (i added css="public/ccs/style.css" in my page html)

Comment: Add '/' before public ...Example css="/public/ccs/style.css" @Nastro

Comment: Im tried to mysite.com/public/css/style.css in a browser url search. No luck.

Comment: Is your nginx running ? @Nastro

Comment: yes. After editing my server conf I restarted nginx with systemctl restart nginx and after checked nginx status by systemctl status nginx. It's running.

Comment: Why I am asking is that.... the static files (CSS, etc )w ill be served even without nodejs app running.. Double check this line *root /PATH_TO_YOUR_NODE_APP_PUBLIC_DIRECTORY* in config file

Comment: Checked this line. I make an experiment - putted hello world index.html in public folder, shutdown my node app and go to / route. See - The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later. (nginx says)

Comment: I have done this for my side projects, bro, @Nastro It will work. Give a try. cheers

Comment: per nginx docs - root /PATH_TO_YOUR_NODE_APP_PUBLIC_DIRECTORY should not be within the 'location' block. If you run nginx -t , it should fail

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express, you only need to configure express.static. Docs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

If you want to configure it from nginx add a layer to your path like this.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  my-site.com;
    root         /home/myuser/site/public;

    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
    }

    location @nodejs {
           proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000";
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```